# Can't change the presentation and transition styles of modal views in Xcode (iPad)

Tags: ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm currently having some trouble with modal views and popovers. It might be the same problem, but I'm not sure.

The problem I'm having with modal views is that I can't change the animation or transition style. For instance, I write

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:IpModal animated:YES];
```

but the modal view still appears full screen with its original transition style.

Also, the problem I'm having with popovers is pretty similar. Even though I call the dismissPopover:animated: method with "NO" as the parameter, the transition is still animated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26):

`modalPresentationStyle` and `modalTransitionStyle` apply to the view controller that *is to be presented modally*, not the controller doing the presenting.

Your code should be

```
IpModal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
IpModal.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:IpModal animated:YES];
```

Comment: +1 This also works when setting at destination viewcontroller for style to dismiss back by setting those to itself. For example the case of previewing viewcontroller via force touch, setting transition of dismissing seems to be flexible by doing at the destination side.

Comment: @haxpor can you please explain your comment in more detail?

Comment: @LanceSamaria If I recall it correctly. It's also flexible to set dismissing transition style at the *destination VC* ; in my case the VC that is going to be shown. So no for management code at the originated VC where it presents another.

Answer (score 4):

I did this in custom segue.

```
UIViewController* src = self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController* dst = self.destinationViewController;

src.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
dst.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[src presentModalViewController:dst animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#import yourViewController.m //already present
#import destinationVieController.m //to be added by programmer

//custom function to call destination controller

-(void)callDestinationViewController{

    destinationViewController *dest = [[destinationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"destinationViewController" bundle:nil];

    dest.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:dest animated:YES];

  }

//custom function can be called on event fire or action call
```

Hope This Helps !

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try using one of these two methods to present the popover controller, depending on where you want it to appear, rather than `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

```
– presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
– presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
```